# Theorem of Catalan - minimal ruled surfaces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

I'm trying to prove the Theorem of Catalan of minimal ruled surfaces, which states that the only minimal ruled surfaces are planes and helicoids.

According to [Wolfgang Kühnel's Differential Geometry](http://bookstore.ams.org/stml-77) [exercise 12, ch. 3](https://books.google.de/books?id=qNBYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=theorem+of+catalan+ruled+surface&source=bl&ots=CYtjRsQ4wq&sig=fdmuby8Wx6is12CqLLviRbnH-OI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJjJLY_u_QAhVLvxQKHe1bAUQQ6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=theorem%20of%20catalan%20ruled%20surface&f=false), one should first verify that the Gaussian curvature $K$ and the mean curvature $H$ of a ruled surface

$$ f(t,s) = c(t) + sX(t) $$

given by standard parameters (i.e. such that $\lVert X \rVert = \lVert X' \rVert = 1$ and $\langle c', X' \rangle = 0$), are given by

$$ K = \frac{-\lambda}{(\lambda ^2 + s^2)^2} \quad \quad H = -\frac{1}{2 (\lambda^2 + s^2)^\frac{3}{2}} (Js^2 + \lambda' s + \lambda(\lambda J + F))$$

where

$$ F := \langle c', X \rangle $$
$$ \lambda := \langle c' \times X, X' \rangle = \det (c', X, X') $$
$$ J := \langle X'', X \times X' \rangle = \det (X, X', X'') $$

each of which is a function only of $t$.

With this proved, one should be able to determine all minimal ruled surfaces "with ease".

I have proved the expressions for $K$ and $H$ after somewhat lengthy calculations, but I don't know how to use them in order to prove that the plane and the helicoid are the only minimal ruled surfaces. I know that for a surface to be minimal, $H = 0$.

Comment: Please give your  result for $H$. I could not see why $K$ is relevant, except for the negative sign.

Comment: What is your $F$?

Comment: [Here](https://goo.gl/5JZjT8) is a document detailing all of the computations, plus the calculation of $H, F, \lambda$ and $J$ for a helicoid.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rPvN_yGkEdUHF5U1N0Q2RTUjA/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-WRsJc_6RQ6e4sndZjpOhyQ) is an updated link to the above document.

Answer (score 1):

$H = 0$ tells you that $Js^2 + \lambda' s + \lambda(\lambda J + F) \equiv 0$. Since this is a quadratic polynomial in $s$ whose coefficients (which depend only on $t$) must vanish, we get $J = 0, \lambda' = 0$, which means $\lambda$ is constant, and $J = \lambda F = 0$. Therefore $X''$ is a linear combination of $X$ and $X'$, but since $\langle  X'', X' \rangle = 0$ (because $||X'|| \equiv 1$) and $\langle X'', X \rangle \equiv - 1$ (because $$||X|| \equiv 1 \implies \langle X, X' \rangle = 0\implies \langle X'', X \rangle = -||X'||^2 = - 1$$), it follows that $X'' = -X$, i.e, $X$ defines a circle. If $\lambda = 0$ then we get $K = H = 0$ and the surface must be a plane. If $\lambda \neq 0$ then we must have $F = 0$, which implies $c' = \lambda X \wedge X'$ and differentiating we get $X'' = 0$, therefore $X$ must define a line perpendicular to the circle defined by $X$. Without loss of generality we can suppose that $c$ and $X$ are given by $c(t) = (0, 0, ct)$ for some $c \neq 0$ and $X(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t), 0)$. It's easy to see that the correspending parametrization defines a helicoid, which proves Catalan's theorem.